# Letting the user choose an activity for a certain file format with private in-app option with the usual dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, format

Let's say, my Android app manages a certain file format that can be opened by an external app by means of sending an intent. My app sends the intent and the user is prompted to choose which app has to handle it.

I would like that my app has an activity that also can handle that format itself. 
This activity in my app has not to be accessible to the user from another app that sends the same type of intent to open the above mentioned file format.

So it should be just a choice for the user what app to use, even my app itself, when my app sends the intent with that file format.

But I do not want that the activity in my app that is able to accept that format could be chosen from other apps as sink of the format.

Is it possible mantaining the same app-picker dialog that Android shows to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`:

```
  // Intent original is an Intent to start your own internal activity
  // Intent toChooseFrom is an Intent to start third-party activities;
  // String title is the title to display as part of the chooser

  Intent chooser=Intent.createChooser(toChooseFrom, title);

  chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
    new Intent[] {original});

  // call startActivity()/startActivityForResult(), passing in chooser
```

Your internal activity will appear in the chooser (usually towards the front) along with any third-party activities that can handle the request. Your activity does not need an `<intent-filter>` or otherwise be exported.

Comment: Is there shown the usual flag to automatically confirm the same choiche for the next times? Is that code suitable for the future too?

Comment: @P5music: "Is there shown the usual flag to automatically confirm the same choiche for the next times?" -- no, I do not think so. When you call `createChooser()` manually like this, you block the "always" option on the selection.

Comment: @P5music: AFAIK, what you want is not possible.

Comment: Is it possible to know what was the choice, to save it and so to be able to manage somehow the next time?

Comment: @P5music: Only on Android 5.1+, using [the three-parameter version of `createChooser()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.IntentSender%29).

Comment: Does not the returned intent of createChooser bear some useful information like that?

Comment: @P5music: No. That is the `Intent` to *show* the chooser. The user has not seen the chooser yet, and will not do so until you call `startActivity()`/`startActivityForResult()`.